# zeus + guard + rspec "Couldn't find test file 'rspec'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, guard, zeus

My Rails application has installed the `guard-zeus` and `rspec-rails` gems.

My `Guardfile` has the default watch code generated by `guard init zeus`

I run `guard`. When I save a file, specs in that file run correctly.

However, when I press return in the `guard` console, I expect it to run the entire test suite. It attempts to do so, but throws `Couldn't find test file 'rspec'`

If I start `zeus` on its own (without guard), I can `zeus start` and then `zeus rake` successfully.

I can't figure out what "rspec" file `guard` is looking for. This is my Guardfile:

```
guard 'zeus' do
  watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb$})                           { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})                           { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$})  { |m| ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb", "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb", "spec/requests/#{m[1]}_spec.rb"] }
end
```

I've tried specifying the `cmd: bundle exec rake` in the guard block.

Additional info:

`custom_plan.rb` looks like this:

```
require 'zeus/rails'

class CustomPlan < Zeus::Rails

  # def my_custom_command
  #  # see https://github.com/burke/zeus/blob/master/docs/ruby/modifying.md
  # end

end

Zeus.plan = CustomPlan.new
```

and `zeus.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "command": "ruby -rubygems -r./custom_plan -eZeus.go",

  "plan": {
    "boot": {
      "default_bundle": {
        "development_environment": {
          "prerake": {"rake": []},
          "console": ["c"],
          "server": ["s"],
          "generate": ["g"],
          "destroy": ["d"],
          "dbconsole": []
        },
        "test_environment": {
          "test_helper": {"test": ["rspec"]}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i simply added an empty file called rspec. It got rid of the error but not sure it helped. My time did not decrease

Answer (score 1):

Would you mind trying this, please?

```
guard 'zeus', :rspec => true, :bundler => true  do
  watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb$})                           { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})                           { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$})  { |m| ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb", "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb", "spec/requests/#{m[1]}_spec.rb"] }
end
```

Please also paste in the contents of `zeus.json` and `custom_plan.rb`.

If you're missing either of those files, please run `zeus init`. This will create `zeus.json` and `custom_plan.rb`.

Then, edit zeus.json to include only the tasks for which you’ll use Zeus. Mine looks like this:

```
{
  "command": "ruby -rubygems -r./custom_plan -eZeus.go",

  "plan": {
    "boot": {
      "default_bundle": {
        "development_environment": {
          "prerake": {"rake": []},
          "runner": ["r"],
          "console": ["c"],
          "server": ["s"],
          "generate": ["g"],
          "destroy": ["d"],
          "dbconsole": []
        },
        "test_environment": {
          "test_helper": {"test": ["rspec"]}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried it. Still same `Couldn't find test file 'rspec'!`

Comment: Please also paste in the contents of zeus.json and custom_plan.rb assuming you have one.

Comment: I don't have either of those.

Comment: Ah, you should have those files. Please run zeus init and try the added instructions above.

Comment: Generated and added to question above!

Comment: Great! Can you also add `spec/spec_helper.rb` please? Maybe we should set up a github repo with all these files? :D

Comment: I set up a repo. Wasn't able to reproduce my actual issue, but getting a different issue right now :/. If I can get this working, I can copy the configuration to my actual projet! [https://github.com/mehulkar/guard-zeus-rspec](https://github.com/mehulkar/guard-zeus-rspec)